# GCC Format attribute not working on function pointer with "using" alias

Tags: c++, attributes, gcc-warning

As the [ISO C++ Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#t43-prefer-using-over-typedef-for-defining-aliases) recommends, we should use `using` instead of `typedef`. However, recently I had to code some debug logging where the **attribute** would be helpful for compile-time diagnostics.

When I tried applying the `using` keyword, this did not seem to work:

```cpp
using logger_cb = void(*)(const char*, va_list) 
__attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0)));
```

The error is:

```
<source>:4:48: error: expected ';' before '__attribute__'
    4 | using logger_cb = void(*)(const char*, va_list) __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0))); // <-- uncommenting this won't work
      |                                                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                                                ;
```

However, using `typedef` it works:

```cpp
typedef void (*logger_cb)(const char*, va_list) 
__attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0)));
```

I cannot figure out if my syntax is wrong or this simply is not supported with the using keyword. Does some guru know about this?

#### Link to example: https://godbolt.org/z/qWdxWq6Gx

Comment: putting the attribute in front seems to work for `using` [see example](https://godbolt.org/z/Yof7f1fYa), it should even be before the `=` sign as per [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Comment: The `__attribute__` needs to go before the declarator, which makes the using version work. I'm not sure your `typedef` version is actually getting the attribute applied.

Comment: [Is __attribute__ ((__packed__)) ignored on a typedef declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12213866/is-attribute-packed-ignored-on-a-typedef-declaration) and [Using __attribute__ with typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056935/using-attribute-with-typedef)

Comment: [Is it allowed to create a `typedef` for a function with attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73204218/is-it-allowed-to-create-a-typedef-for-a-function-with-attributes)

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai, Changed the code example and question as you suggested.

Comment: It should be `using logger_cb __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0))) =   void(*)(const char*, va_list); // <-- uncommenting this won't work
`

Comment: @SupAl I've updated the answer to use the standard `[[]]` so there is no need to put the same in the question(note also that questions should not include answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I tried applying the using keyword, this did not seem to work:

The placement of the ***optional*** `attribute-specifier-seq` must be **after the *identifier*** in an *alias-declaration*. This can be seen from [alias declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias):

> Alias declarations are declarations with the following syntax:
>
> ```
> using identifier attr (optional) = type-id ;  (1)     
> template < template-parameter-list >
> using identifier attr (optional) = type-id ;  (2)
> ```
>
> attr  -   optional sequence of any number of attributes

The same can be seen from [gram.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:alias-declaration):

> ```
> alias-declaration:
> using identifier attribute-specifier-seqopt = defining-type-id ;
> ```

---

This means that the **standard way** to use `using` here is as shown below:

```
using logger_cb [[gnu::format (__printf__, 1, 0) ]] = void(*)(const char*, va_list);
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/jj3rh86hE)

Comment: Thanks. I just want to follow up, after reading more about the attribute specifier, that it can be stated more standard-y with:
`using logger_cb [[gnu::format (__printf__, 1, 0) ]] = void(*)(const char*, va_list);`

Comment: @SupAl Yes, updated with `[[ ]]`. Also added a link to [gram.dcl](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.pre#nt:alias-declaration).

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to C++11 attribute syntax, it goes in that position to apply to the function type `void(const char*, va_list)`:

```cpp
using logger_cb = void (*)(const char*, va_list)
[[__gnu__::__format__(__printf__, 1, 0)]];
```

This is where standard attributes that apply to the function types are ["supposed"](https://wg21.link/dcl.fct#1.sentence-2) to go, but this alternative position works for the `__attribute__` syntax too:

```cpp
using logger_cb = void ([[__gnu__::__format__(__printf__, 1, 0)]] *)(const char*, va_list);
using logger_cb = void (__attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0))) *)(const char*, va_list);
```

(with the caveat that this only works because its before a `*`, and wouldn't work if `logger_cb` was an alias for a function type)

---

You can also apply it to the declaration (`logger_cb`):

```cpp
using logger_cb [[__gnu__::__format__(__printf__, 1, 0)]]
    = void (*)(const char*, va_list);
using logger_cb __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0)))
    = void (*)(const char*, va_list);
```

Or to the pointer type `void(*)(const char*, va_list)`:

```cpp
using logger_cb = void (* [[__gnu__::__format__(__printf__, 1, 0)]])(const char*, va_list);
using logger_cb = void (* __attribute__ ((__format__ (__printf__, 1, 0))))(const char*, va_list);
```

Since they all end up doing the same thing for the `__format__` attribute, but note that this isn't the case for other attributes.

Comment: Nice with some expounding! What is the most general way of applying this syntax (i.e., the one that covers the most cases).

Comment: @SupAl There are very subtle differences between the three. For most function attributes, if you apply them to the pointer type or the function type, they have the same meaning. I would stick with the very first one with the C++11 syntax, since you are semantically applying it to the function type it makes the most sense. Here is an example of the difference between applying to the declaration and applying to a type: https://godbolt.org/z/8jME95bch